# asp.net projects using common project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, architecture

I have a solution in ASP.NET Core. This solution has multiple projects:

- Domain: database first entities
- Repository
- Service
- ViewModel: models
- Web: web site

Now, I need to develope 2 more projects, an API and another web site.
Tjose new projects are going to use the same database structure, so the DOMAIN project would be common for them.

How can I do that? Do I need a new solution and add the DOMAIN project as a dll or can I add another web site to the main solution and switch between them?

One thing, I need to compile and publish the previous web site, the new web site and the api separately.

Thanks.

Comment: Personally I would add the API and second UI to the same solution. It will make it easier to keep your versions up to date. When you change a shared component you can increment all projects in the solution.
Your idea about publishing at different times may not work though, if you are using EF then any changes to the entities/db will mean publishing all of the UI/API's as they are sharing the underlying context. If you only publish one with db changes then the others will throw an exception as the db will not match what is expected.

Comment: Thanks James, no, if I change the db, all projects have to be published, of course. But I'm thinking in the scenario where just one of the UI changes or the API, I'd like to be able to publish just that project, and don't have to do with others.